# Can Alexa be trained to use preferred volume levels?

Tags: alexa, amazon-echo, smart-assistants

Is there a way to train Alexa to use preferred volume levels, such that Alexa

- plays music at volume X
- replies at volume Y
- sets volume to 0 every night at 9 PM, and back to last set volume at 6 AM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment, it is impossible to set a schedule for Alexa's volume, according to [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/amazonecho/comments/4maoft/any_idea_how_to_automatically_reduce_the_volume/). Instead, you must manually tell Alexa to *"set volume to 0"* at night, then *set volume to [your preferred value]"* in the morning.

I believe you can set the alarm/notification volume separately to the master volume in the app (certainly [as of December 2016](http://www.echotalk.org/index.php?topic=1248.0)), but I'm unaware of a setting to change music volume separately to voice volume for Alexa's replies.

As always, it may be worth [sending feedback](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=201601960) requesting this feature if there isn't a solution available; Amazon's team does seem to listen to and prioritise requested features.