# How can tell Alexa to use a different sound level for Notifications

Tags: amazon-echo, sound

I have a Fibaro Home Automation system with multiple Alexa devices.  When someone leaves any of the 3 garage doors open, I have Alexa automatically notify us between 8pm and 11pm, hourly that the garage door is still open.

This has been working fine for months.  All of a sudden these Notifications are whisper quiet on all the devices.  They are not automatically adjusted for the background noise level either.  If the TV is on, then I almost never hear them.

**Is there a way to get Alexa to use the same volume level for everything it does.**

This sounds like [this question](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/1750/can-alexa-be-trained-to-use-preferred-volume-levels) but its different  in that I don't want to customise it, I just want everything the same level.  And its seven years later.

Comment: have you tried asking alexa how to adjust volume?

Comment: Have you already tried https://tripletaptech.org/adjusting-notification-volume-on-alexa-app/

Comment: @kalyanswaroop, I hadn't but I had looked around that area.  With a relook and a little help from the I have found the setting.  The instructions are a little different.  If you don't mind, I might add the updated instructions as an answer.

Comment: @jstola, no, but I had tried "increase volume for notifications" and the response had not made sense as it said `..Alarms and timers volume set to nn`.  But after a relook at the app, I see that the Notifications, Alarms and Timers share the same volume level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On being prompted in comments, I have two ways of doing it.  It is worth noting that the `Alarms`, `Timers` and `Notifications` share the volume level.

**Voice**

- "Alexa, set volume for notifications to 6"
- or "Alexa, increase the volume for notifications"

**On the App in 2024**

- Open Alex app
- Select `Devices` on the bottom
- Press on the drop down `Device Type`
- Select `Echo & Alexa` and press `Apply`
- Scroll and select each Alexa device in turn
- Select `⚙️` settings
- Scroll down to select `Sounds` in the General section
- On the top change the slider for `Alarms, Timers and Notifications` to the desired level.